# Using vim // gvim with unix file format under Windows 10 + Cygwin gets errors from both

Tags: file-formats

This is the [second of two errors](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/28822/10604) posted tonight.  As mentioned before, I did re-install vim/gvim 8.2 to make sure I'd installed it as administrator, as instructed, to make sure the batch files, etc., got installed.

I move files around between Linux and Windows constantly, and use the
unix file format for everything to avoid constantly having to do
`:%s/^M//g` every time I move a file around.  I had this silenced (by
some magic, it just finally shut up).  I have `set fileformat=unix` in my
.vimrc as the first non-comment line.  But when opening the first
file, it will always give me the following errors (having to add blank lines to keep them from becoming one giant mess of a paragraph - Each error is followed by `line 1`):

```
Error detected while processing C:\jim\bin\Vim\vim82\plugin\getscriptPlugin.vim:
Error detected while processing C:\jim\bin\Vim\vim82\plugin\gzip.vim:
Error detected while processing C:\jim\bin\Vim\vim82\plugin\logiPat.vim:
Error detected while processing C:\jim\bin\Vim\vim82\plugin\manpager.vim:
Error detected while processing C:\jim\bin\Vim\vim82\plugin\matchparen.vim:
Error detected while processing C:\jim\bin\Vim\vim82\plugin\netrwPlugin.vim:
Error detected while processing C:\jim\bin\Vim\vim82\plugin\rrhelper.vim:
Error detected while processing C:\jim\bin\Vim\vim82\plugin\spellfile.vim:
Error detected while processing C:\jim\bin\Vim\vim82\plugin\tarPlugin.vim:
Error detected while processing C:\jim\bin\Vim\vim82\plugin\tohtml.vim:
Error detected while processing C:\jim\bin\Vim\vim82\plugin\vimballPlugin.vim:
Error detected while processing C:\jim\bin\Vim\vim82\plugin\zipPlugin.vim:
Error detected while processing C:\jim\bin\Vim\vim82\menu.vim:
Error detected while processing C:\jim\bin\Vim\vim82\autoload\paste.vim:
```

Each of the above is followed by: `W15: Warning: Wrong line separator, ^M may be missing`

If I exit out of vim//gvim, I get the same errors again.  If I use `:e foo.bar` to simply edit the file again, or another file, or split, etc., I
don't get the same errors.  I looked at the various .vim files, saved
them in unix format, and thought that might stop these error messages.
No such luck.

Comment: `:set fileformat=unix` doesn't do what you think it does. See the "update" section of my answer here [Why isn't carriage return shown as ^M in my Vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/27556/why-isnt-carriage-return-shown-as-m-in-my-vim/27557#27557)

Comment: Also, I edit files in gvim with unix line ending and those with windows line endings all the time and I never see `^M`. That's because the default `'ffs'` setting mentioned in my referenced answer is designed to keep that stuff hidden.

Comment: `:h W15` and set your `fileformats` option correctly

Comment: In my .vimrc, the first non-commented line (and .vimrc is in unix format, btw) is:
set fileformats=unix

Ok, here's a possibility:  could it be one of vim's startup files (e.g., all those .vim files that it's complaining about (except not those, specifically...like I said, I saved all of those in unix format, so I'm *guessing* that it must be something opened before them.  So what is the order of files opened by vim that could have a ^M that would throw that error?

Also remember, this is ONLY happening in gvim, NOT vim.  In case that matters.

Comment: Ok, I tried several different settings for fileformats and fileformat=unix.  I had ffs set to [empty], unix, and unix,dos.  Each time (after saving .vimrc, of course), I got the same series of warnings in gvim, but NOT in vim.  And fileformats=[whichever of the three I'm testing at the time] is immediately before fileformat=unix (I learned the full option decades ago...ff and ffs just this morning).

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is:

```
set fileformats=unix,dos
```

In your vimrc, and not manually set `'fileformat'`. This makes unix the default `'fileformat'` for new files, while allowing Vim to properly handle DOS file formats.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a perfect solution, but I did silence those warnings.  Seems all of the files that gvim (again, not vim) was griping about were in the vim 8.2 distribution, all .vim files.  I just set those to dos format.  So I gather those files are loaded prior to loading my ~/.vimrc, where the first two non-commented lines are:

set ffs=
set ff=unix

I also copied what was left in my old ~/.exrc file (from many decades ago, before vim existed and I used normal vi) and renamed it to get it out of the way (for some reason, I can't convince myself to rm old config files; oh wait, I know why, it always eventually comes back to bite me when I do).  It was also one of the files gvim was complaining about.

So I'm happy.  Thanks, everyone, for pointing me in the right directions to find the above solution (or do we call it a band-aid?).  It works.  Good enough.